# when i have 3 package.json, npm install only two package.json

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, npm-scripts, npm-start

I have 3 package.json. one is the root package.json, and second, third are local library package.json.

package.json
|
|ㅡpackage.json(lib a)
|
|ㅡpackage.json(lib b)

when I 'npm install' in root directory, only root package.json and lib a are installed.
lib b module are installed but not whole module.

[image: lib a module]

this is complete module

[image: lib b modules]

and this is module which doesn't installed completly.

it makes me crazy!

lib a and b have same dependencies.
but there are no error message.

what can i do!!!!
help me...

thank you ...

Comment: @AarushKumar oh can't i?

Comment: you can but i prefer one is enough

Comment: also which libraries are you using